# Printing dynamic content - replacing in clone

Tags: jquery, printing

I want to print a page where content is dynamically added. I try to do it like this:

```
$("body").on("click", function() {

    function preparePrint() {
        var print_window = window.open();
        var print_document = $("div.container").clone();

        print_document.find('.block').each(replaceWith("X"));

        print_window.document.open();
        print_window.document.write(print_document.html());
        print_window.document.close();
        print_window.print();
        print_window.close();
    }

    $("#print").click(function() {
        preparePrint();
    })
})
```

With every click, the contents of the `div` with class `container` are cloned. `container` holds some `div`s and tables. In the clone, I try to find elements with the class `block` and replace them with an upper case "X". `block` is the class that is dynamically added to some `td`s.

Then, I open a new window and place the html content of the clone in there. Then I print it.

So far, so good, but the replacing is not working - why? I also tried `document.write`, `html()` and `text()` to get the "X" in there, but without effect. I always end up with a white page, so maybe there is something wrong with the clone also.

Comment: You need to expose the object in the each function, and then run code against it. You need to change the replaceWith functionality with -> `print_document.find('.block').each(function(){ $(this).replaceWidth("X") });`

Comment: Thanks! Using your code (Btw: There is a small typo in there - see `replaceWidth` needs to be `replaceWith`) it works! I've also removed the `on` handler as it's not needed. So, could post your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_document.find('.block').each(function(){ $(this).replaceWith("X") });
```